# C++ map: operator[] with custom class does not work (always returns 0)

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I'm trying to implement a MinHeap, where objects on the heap are WorkerNodes. My method returns map which is intended to allow client code to determine which WorkerNode indices have changed from the minHeapify operation.

```
std::cout << "heapifying " << heap_[root] << "from index " << root << "\n.";
    int size = heap_.size();
    bool swapped = false;
    std::map<WorkerNode, int> tracker;

    for (int i = root; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int leftChild = 2 * i + 1;
            if (leftChild < 0 || leftChild >= size)
                break;
            int rightChild = 2 * i + 2;
            int smallerChild = leftChild;
            if (rightChild < size && heap_[rightChild] < heap_[leftChild])
                smallerChild = rightChild;

            if (heap_[i] <= heap_[smallerChild])
                break;

            // index tracking

            tracker[heap_[i]] = smallerChild;
            tracker[heap_[smallerChild]] = i;

            std::cout << "**\n\n"
                      << heap_[i] << " has moved to " << smallerChild;
            std::cout << ", and " << heap_[smallerChild] << " has moved to " << i << "\n**";

            // swap heap_[i] and heap_[smallerChild]
            swapped = true;
            T temp = heap_[i];
            heap_[i] = heap_[smallerChild];
            heap_[smallerChild] = temp;
            i = smallerChild;
        }
    }
    if (!swapped) // avoids bad access
    {
        tracker[heap_[root]] = root;

        for (auto &itm : tracker)
        {
            std::cout << "**\n"
                      << itm.first << " is at " << itm.second << "!!!\n";
        }
        std::cout << "**\nno swap; " << heap_[root] << " stays at " << tracker[heap_[root]] << "\n**";
    }

    return tracker;
```

Here is the ouput that I am seeing:

```
heapifying W1-1from index 0
.**
W1-1 is at 0!!!
**
no swap; W1-1 stays at 0
**heapifying W2-2from index 1
.**
W2-2 is at 1!!!
**
no swap; W2-2 stays at 0
**heapifying W3-3from index 2
.**
W3-3 is at 2!!!
**
no swap; W3-3 stays at 0
**heapifying W0-3from index 3
.**
W0-3 is at 3!!!
**
no swap; W0-3 stays at 0
```

This issue was brought to my attention when running test cases, where I am doing something like this:

```
WorkerNode key("W4", 2);
    // after two decrements, its index should still be 3.
    BOOST_TEST(tracker[key] == 3);
```

And getting output like this:

```
error: in "minheap_test_suite/case6": check tracker[key] == 3 has failed [0 != 3]
```

So from what I can tell, The pre-exit for loop in my minHeapify method confirms that the proper data is being inserted into the map, but when I try to access this data using the `[]` operator, it is unable to locate the WorkerNode-index pairing I just inserted, returning 0 as the value it has probably just default-constructed.

When I tried using `find()` instead of `[]` just now like so:

```
tracker[heap_[root]] = root;

        for (auto &itm : tracker)
        {
            std::cout << "**\n"
                      << itm.first << " is at " << itm.second << "!!!\n";
        }
        int index = tracker.find(heap_[root])->second;
        std::cout << "**\nno swap; " << heap_[root] << " stays at " << index << "\n**";
```

I get the following output:

```
heapifying W1-1from index 0
.**
W1-1 is at 0!!!
**
no swap; W1-1 stays at -1354735968
**heapifying W2-2from index 1
.**
W2-2 is at 1!!!
**
no swap; W2-2 stays at 3233540
```

Here is my WorkerNode.h file, comments removed:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

struct WorkerNode
{
    unsigned numJobs_;     ///< worker job count.
    std::string workerID_; ///< worker ID string.

    explicit WorkerNode() : numJobs_(0), workerID_("") {}

    WorkerNode(std::string id) : numJobs_(0), workerID_(id) {}

    WorkerNode(std::string id, unsigned jobs) : numJobs_(jobs), workerID_(id) {}

    WorkerNode(WorkerNode &&other) : numJobs_(other.numJobs_), workerID_(other.workerID_)
    {
        other.numJobs_ = 0;
        other.workerID_ = "";
    }

    WorkerNode(const WorkerNode &other) : numJobs_(other.numJobs_), workerID_(other.workerID_) {}

    WorkerNode &operator=(const WorkerNode &other)
    {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        this->numJobs_ = other.numJobs_;
        this->workerID_ = other.workerID_;
        return *this;
    }

    WorkerNode &operator=(WorkerNode &&other)
    {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        this->numJobs_ = other.numJobs_;
        this->workerID_ = other.workerID_;
        other.numJobs_ = 0;
        other.workerID_ = "";
        return *this;
    }

    ~WorkerNode() {}

    bool operator<(const WorkerNode &rhs) const
    {
        return *this <= rhs;
    }

    bool operator<=(const WorkerNode &rhs) const
    {
        if (numJobs_ < rhs.numJobs_)
            return true;
        else if (rhs.numJobs_ < numJobs_)
            return false;
        else
        {
            return workerID_.compare(rhs.workerID_) <= 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }

    bool operator==(const WorkerNode &rhs) const
    {
        if (numJobs_ == rhs.numJobs_ && workerID_ == rhs.workerID_)
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void operator--()
    {
        if (numJobs_ > 0)
            numJobs_ -= 1;
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        numJobs_ += 1;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const WorkerNode &n)
    {
        out << n.workerID_ << "-" << n.numJobs_;
        return out;
    }
};
```

WTF am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Okay folks, here is my reprex. My apologies for the prior nonsensical code bloat. This example 100% reproduces my current confusion. Let's get to the bottom of this thing.

Key.h:

```
// user-defined struct, intended to be used as a map key.

#include <string>
#include <ostream>

struct Key
{
    std::string id;
    unsigned jobs;

    Key(std::string id_ = "", unsigned jobs_ = 0) : id(id_), jobs(jobs_) {}

    bool operator<(const Key &rhs) const
    {
        if (jobs < rhs.jobs)
            return true;
        else if (rhs.jobs < jobs)
            return false;
        else
            return id.compare(rhs.id) <= 0 ? true : false;
    }

    bool operator<=(const Key &rhs) const
    {
        if (jobs < rhs.jobs)
            return true;
        else if (rhs.jobs < jobs)
            return false;
        else
            return id.compare(rhs.id) <= 0 ? true : false;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Key &key)
    {
        o << key.id << "-" << key.jobs;
        return o;
    }
};
```

MinHeap.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include "Key.h"

struct MinHeap
{
    std::vector<Key> heap;

    std::map<Key, int> minHeapify(int root)
    {
        std::map<Key, int> tracker;
        for (int i = 0; i < heap.size(); ++i)
            tracker[heap[i]] = i;
        return tracker;
    }

    std::map<Key, int> insert(const Key &key)
    {
        heap.push_back(key);
        return minHeapify(heap.size() - 1);
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MinHeap.h"

int main()
{
    MinHeap heap;
    std::map<Key, int> tracker;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Key key("Key" + std::to_string(i), i);
        tracker = heap.insert(key);

        //checking tracker contents using auto for loop
        std::cout << "tracker keyindex contents: ";
        for (auto &itm : tracker)
        {
            std::cout << itm.first << " ::: " << itm.second << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";

        //checking key and tracker[key], which should reflect
        //each other as well as the operation done in minHeapify.

        /// *** what tracker[key] is actually printing ***
        std::cout << "tracker[key] = " << tracker[key] << std::endl;
        /// **********************************************

        /// *** what tracker[key] is expected to be printing ***
        std::cout << "actual tracker key index: " << key.jobs << std::endl;
        /// ****************************************************
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run main.cpp yourself. The big problem here is the last two print statements. The prior for loop confirms that the expected Keys are indeed being returned by the `minHeapify(int)` operation and have the expected index.

However, attempts to subindex using `[Key]` into `map<Key,int>` **does not** return the expected index.

Hopefully, I have illustrated the confusion a little clearer.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers

Comment: I don't see your `[]` operator declared or defined anywhere. If it's not here can you please include that. [example]

Comment: `std::map` uses `operator<` by default to order keys, but your `operator<` implementation looks wrong: `bool operator<(const WorkerNode &rhs) const { return *this <= rhs; }`. You shouldn't be allowing equality in a less-than comparison. Per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map): "*Everywhere the standard library uses the `Compare` requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, **two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other**: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.*"

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's hard telling where the problem could be with bits and pieces of code.

Comment: @John See above for a reprex. Regarding `[]`, that is defined by `std::map`; there is no need to define `[]` for `Key`, that would not make sense. I am not subindexing into `Key` itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You make a strong point. My reasoning for doing such a thing in `operator <=` was an attempt to follow DRY. If you see the above reprex, you will notice that `operator <=` and `operator <` for `Key` are exactly the same. Any suggestions as to how I could avoid the repetition (in addition to resolving my confusion) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @RSahu My apologies. Please see the above edit.

Comment: Please, please, learn what a minimal reproducible example is. This is about 10 times more code than needed to reproduce the problem in the title (and I do mean the updated version). Also, while trying to reproduce the issue in a minimal example, you will most likely find the problem on your own. Also, whenever `operator<` uses `operator<=` in its implementation, you should take a closer look. Why are you doing this: `return id.compare(rhs.id) <= 0 ? true : false;` ?

Comment: @DeducibleSteak I did my absolute very best to give you guys a reprex using [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). **I am sorry, I am trying my best.** I included everything I thought would be necessary and nothing more. What should I have not included, sir? As for the return statement, my application intends to have nodes with unique id strings. **Thus, they will never be equal.** I suppose I should not have used `<=` in `operator<` as it can lead to confusion, but indeed they will never be equal in my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, I think, is already identified in comments by Remy Lebeau.

Your implementation of `Key::operator<` does not meet the requirements of [strictly weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), as required of a type to be usable as the key in a `std::map`.

You need a minor change in the implementation.

```
bool operator<(const Key &rhs) const
{
    if (jobs < rhs.jobs)
        return true;
    else if (rhs.jobs < jobs)
        return false;
    else
        return id.compare(rhs.id) <  0 ? true : false; // Needs to be <, not <=
}
```

You can simplify the function using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
bool operator<(const Key &rhs) const
{
   std::tie(jobs, id) < std::tie(rhs.jobs, rhs.id);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. I assumed that because I designed my keys to be unique (each has a unique id string), something like that could not possibly cause a malfunction in the internal working of `map`. I will have to investigate this topic a little deeper. I knew about the need for `operator<` with custom key classes, but I was unaware of how strict it was. Thank you for this.

Comment: @the_mackster - think about it this way: how would you find if a number is in a sorted list of numbers, if your only tool was operator<, and when you tested against a matching/equal number, it would say: "one of these is strictly smaller than the other" ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Key {
  std::string id;
  unsigned    jobs;
  bool operator<(const Key & rhs) const {
    if (jobs < rhs.jobs)
      return true;
    else if (rhs.jobs < jobs)
      return false;
    else
      return id.compare(rhs.id) <= 0 ? true : false;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::map<Key, int> m;
  m[Key { "Key0", 0 }] = 0;
  m[Key { "Key1", 1 }] = 1;
  m[Key { "Key2", 2 }] = 2;
  std::cout << m[Key { "Key0", 0 }] << std::endl;
  std::cout << m[Key { "Key1", 1 }] << std::endl;
  std::cout << m[Key { "Key2", 2 }] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Is this easier to grasp? Is this easier for people to help you with?

Can you yourself find the problem now?

Comment: Thank you. I will do better in the future. Sorry for causing such an inconvenience in your world of perfection.

Comment: @the_mackster, it's not about a world of perfection. It's about making sure that you do your best to minimize the amount of code that produces the problem. Some times, even that in itself will let you resolve the problem without outside help. The other thing is it's easy for others to find the source of the problem if you present the minimal amount of code that produces the problem.

Comment: Well, snark aside, narrowing down the scope of where your problem could possibly be, will not only help you get better and faster answers on SO/other forums, it will also make you a better programmer and help you find the solutions on your own. I will bet you $10 that, had you stripped your code down to this small example, you would have immediatelly seen the problem - there are not a lot of places for it to hide.

Comment: You are both right. I just get a little frustrated when asking folks on SO about bugs. I could definitely be doing things to make it easier for myself and others on SO to solve the bugs. I guess I just get a little tired of hearing the same tone of annoyance from people on here when the question I've posted isn't phrased exactly as it should be. Thanks for the help, both of you.

Comment: No problem. We've all been there and it's easy to do the same thing when answering questions, too.